# while appending records in Exl sheet using apache poi lib, the text font colors are applying to first row ,rest of the rows showing default color

Tags: apache-poi

this is the code for generating exl file.every time when i am appending records to exl file. i am setting setter of the  font again. for first time  entry in exl file, styles are applying.but when i am adding next entry to exl file, this time style is not applying.

```
    public class ExcelOutputWriter implements OutputWriter {

    private List<String> headerList;
    private List<List<String>> rowsList;
    private List<BGVInformationVO> allBGVInformationVOList = new ArrayList<>();
    private XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private XSSFSheet sheet;
    private XSSFCellStyle headerCellStyle;
    private XSSFCellStyle fontGreenStyle;
    private XSSFCellStyle fontRedStyle;
    private XSSFCellStyle fontOrangeStyle;
    private XSSFCellStyle fontYellowStyle;
    private XSSFCellStyle dateCellStyle;
    private XSSFCellStyle dtlCellStyle;
    private int rowCount;

    Logger logger = BGVerificationLogger.getLogger(ExcelOutputWriter.class);

    @Override
    public void setHeaderList(List<String> headerList) {
        this.headerList = headerList;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getRowsList() {
        return rowsList;
    }

    public void setRowsList(List<List<String>> rowsList) {
        this.rowsList = rowsList;
    }

    public XSSFWorkbook getWorkbook() {
        return workbook;
    }

    public void setWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        this.workbook = workbook;
    }

    public XSSFSheet getSheet() {
        return sheet;
    }

    public void setSheet(XSSFSheet sheet) {
        this.sheet = sheet;
    }

    public XSSFCellStyle getHeaderCellStyle() {
        return headerCellStyle;
    }

    public void setHeaderCellStyle(XSSFCellStyle headerCellStyle) {
        this.headerCellStyle = headerCellStyle;
    }

    public XSSFCellStyle getFontGreenStyle() {
        return fontGreenStyle;
    }

    public void setFontGreenStyle(XSSFCellStyle fontGreenStyle) {
        this.fontGreenStyle = fontGreenStyle;
    }

    public XSSFCellStyle getFontRedStyle() {
        return fontRedStyle;
    }

    public void setFontRedStyle(XSSFCellStyle fontRedStyle) {
        this.fontRedStyle = fontRedStyle;
    }

    public XSSFCellStyle getFontYellowStyle() {
        return fontYellowStyle;
    }

    public void setFontYellowStyle(XSSFCellStyle fontYellowStyle) {
        this.fontYellowStyle = fontYellowStyle;
    }

    public XSSFCellStyle getFontOrangeStyle() {
        return fontOrangeStyle;
    }

    public void setFontOrangeStyle(XSSFCellStyle fontOrangeStyle) {
        this.fontOrangeStyle = fontOrangeStyle;
    }

    public XSSFCellStyle getDateCellStyle() {
        return dateCellStyle;
    }

    public void setDateCellStyle(XSSFCellStyle dateCellStyle) {
        this.dateCellStyle = dateCellStyle;
    }

    public XSSFCellStyle getDtlCellStyle() {
        return dtlCellStyle;
    }

    public void setDtlCellStyle(XSSFCellStyle dtlCellStyle) {
        this.dtlCellStyle = dtlCellStyle;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return rowCount;
    }

    public void setRowCount(int rowCount) {
        this.rowCount = rowCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void addBGVInformationVO(BGVInformationVO bgvInformationVO) {
        allBGVInformationVOList.add(bgvInformationVO);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToOutputFile(String fullFileName) throws IOException {
        logger.info("Start writing to Output Excel file: " + fullFileName);
        File outputExcelFile = new File(fullFileName);
        if (outputExcelFile.exists()) {
            writeToExistingWorkBook(fullFileName);
            writeDetailRecord();
        } else {
            createNewExcelWorkBook();
            writeHeaderRecord();
            writeDetailRecord();
        }

        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fullFileName)) 
        {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
        }

        logger.info("Output Excel writing Complete");

     }

    private void createNewExcelWorkBook() throws IOException {
        createWorkBook();
        createSheet(BGVerificationConstant.BGV_SHEET_NAME);
        createHeaderCellStyle();
        createGreenFontStyle();
        createRedFontStyle();
        createYellowFontStyle();
        createOrangeFontStyle();
        createDateCellStyle();
        createDtlCellStyle();
    }

    private void writeToExistingWorkBook(String fullFileName) throws IOException 
    {
        createWorkBook(new FileInputStream(fullFileName));
        getSheet(BGVerificationConstant.BGV_SHEET_NAME);
        //createHeaderCellStyle();
        createGreenFontStyle();
        createRedFontStyle();
        createYellowFontStyle();
        createOrangeFontStyle();
        createDateCellStyle();
        createDtlCellStyle();
        setRowCount(this.sheet.getLastRowNum());
    }

    private void writeHeaderRecord() throws IOException {
        int rowNumCounter = -1;
        int columnCount = -1;

        XSSFRow row = getSheet().createRow(++rowNumCounter);
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
        cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
        cell.setCellValue("Extracted BGV Report ");
        getSheet().addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 16));

        columnCount = -1;
        row = getSheet().createRow(++rowNumCounter);

        for (String headerName : headerList) {
            cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
            cell.setCellValue(headerName);
        }

        setRowCount(rowNumCounter);
    }

    private void writeDetailRecord() throws IOException {
        try {
            for (BGVInformationVO bgvInformationVO : allBGVInformationVOList) {
                XSSFRow row = getSheet().createRow(++rowCount);
                row.setHeight((short) 900);

                int columnCount = -1;
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                cell.setCellStyle(dtlCellStyle);
                cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getVendor());

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                cell.setCellStyle(dtlCellStyle);
                cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getCandidateName());

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                cell.setCellStyle(dtlCellStyle);
                cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getDesignation());

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                cell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
                cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getDateOfInitiation());

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                cell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
                cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getDateOfReport());

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                cell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
                cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getDateOfBirth());

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                cell.setCellStyle(dtlCellStyle);
                cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getCaseRefNumber());

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                if ("green".equalsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getColorCode())) {

                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getColorCode());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontGreenStyle);
                } else if 
          ("orange".equalsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getColorCode())) {

                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getColorCode());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontOrangeStyle);
                }

                else if 
    ("yellow".equalsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getColorCode())) {

                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getColorCode());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontYellowStyle);
                }

                else {
                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getColorCode());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontRedStyle);
                }

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                if 
    (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getEducation(), 
    BGVerificationConstant.NOTCLEAR)
                        || 
   StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getEducation(), 
   BGVerificationConstant.UNABLETOCOMPLETE)) {
                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getEducation());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontRedStyle);
                } else {
                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getEducation());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontGreenStyle);

                }

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                if 
    (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getAddress(), 
    BGVerificationConstant.NOTCLEAR)
                        || 
    StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getAddress(), 
    BGVerificationConstant.UNABLETOCOMPLETE)) {

                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getAddress());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontRedStyle);
                } else {
                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getAddress());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontGreenStyle);
                }

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                if 
    (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getPoliceCase(), 
    BGVerificationConstant.NOTCLEAR)
                        || 
   StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getPoliceCase(), 
   BGVerificationConstant.UNABLETOCOMPLETE)) {

                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getPoliceCase());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontRedStyle);
                } else {

                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getPoliceCase());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontGreenStyle);
                }

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);

                if 
   (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getEmployment(), 
   BGVerificationConstant.NOTCLEAR)
                        || 
   StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getEmployment(), 
   BGVerificationConstant.UNABLETOCOMPLETE)) {

                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getEmployment());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontRedStyle);
                } else {

                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getEmployment());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontGreenStyle);
                }

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                if 
    (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getReference(), 
   BGVerificationConstant.NOTCLEAR)
                        || 
   StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getReference(), 
   BGVerificationConstant.UNABLETOCOMPLETE)) {

                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getReference());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontRedStyle);
                } else {

                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getReference());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontGreenStyle);
                }

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                if 
    (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getCriminalDatabse(), 
   BGVerificationConstant.NOTCLEAR)
                        || 
   StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(bgvInformationVO.getCriminalDatabse(), 
   BGVerificationConstant.UNABLETOCOMPLETE)) {

                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getCriminalDatabse());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontRedStyle);
                } else {

                    cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getCriminalDatabse());
                    cell.setCellStyle(fontGreenStyle);
                }

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                cell.setCellStyle(dtlCellStyle);
                cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getNoOfEmploymentVerified());

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                cell.setCellStyle(dtlCellStyle);
                cell.setCellValue(bgvInformationVO.getNoOfAdrressesVerified());

                cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
                cell.setCellStyle(dtlCellStyle);
                cell.setCellValue("--");

                for (int colNum = 0; colNum < columnCount; colNum++)
                    sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("exception generated in ExcelOutputWriter class " + e);
        }
    }

    private void createDtlCellStyle() {
        XSSFCellStyle detailCellType = workbook.createCellStyle();
        detailCellType.setBorderTop((short) 1); // double lines border
        detailCellType.setBorderLeft((short) 1);
        detailCellType.setBorderRight((short) 1);
        detailCellType.setBorderBottom((short) 1); // single line border
        detailCellType.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        detailCellType.setWrapText(true);
        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
        font.setBold(false);
        font.setBoldweight(XSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);
        detailCellType.setFont(font);

        setDtlCellStyle(detailCellType);
    }

    private void createDateCellStyle() {
        XSSFCellStyle cellStyleDate = workbook.createCellStyle();
        CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        cellStyleDate.setBorderTop((short) 1); // double lines border
        cellStyleDate.setBorderLeft((short) 1);
        cellStyleDate.setBorderRight((short) 1);
        cellStyleDate.setBorderBottom((short) 1); // single line border
        cellStyleDate.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cellStyleDate.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
        font.setBold(false);
        font.setBoldweight(XSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);
        cellStyleDate.setFont(font);

        setDateCellStyle(cellStyleDate);
    }

    // creating font color style
    private void createRedFontStyle() {
        XSSFFont fontRed = workbook.createFont();
        fontRed.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
        fontRed.setColor(HSSFColor.RED.index);
        fontRed.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);

        XSSFCellStyle redFontStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        redFontStyle.setBorderTop((short) 1); // double lines border
        redFontStyle.setBorderLeft((short) 1);
        redFontStyle.setBorderRight((short) 1);
        redFontStyle.setBorderBottom((short) 1); // single line border
        redFontStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //redFontStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
        //redFontStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        redFontStyle.setFont(fontRed);
        redFontStyle.setWrapText(true);
        setFontRedStyle(redFontStyle);
    }

    private void createGreenFontStyle() {
        XSSFFont fontGreen = workbook.createFont();
        fontGreen.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
        fontGreen.setColor(HSSFColor.GREEN.index);
        fontGreen.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);

        XSSFCellStyle greenFontStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        greenFontStyle.setBorderTop((short) 1); // double lines border
        greenFontStyle.setBorderLeft((short) 1);
        greenFontStyle.setBorderRight((short) 1);
        greenFontStyle.setBorderBottom((short) 1); // single line border
        greenFontStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        greenFontStyle.setFont(fontGreen);
        //greenFontStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
        //greenFontStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        greenFontStyle.setWrapText(true);

        setFontGreenStyle(greenFontStyle);
    }

    private void createYellowFontStyle() {
        XSSFFont fontYellow = workbook.createFont();
        fontYellow.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
        fontYellow.setColor(HSSFColor.YELLOW.index);
        fontYellow.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);

        XSSFCellStyle yellowFontStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        yellowFontStyle.setBorderTop((short) 1); // double lines border
        yellowFontStyle.setBorderLeft((short) 1);
        yellowFontStyle.setBorderRight((short) 1);
        yellowFontStyle.setBorderBottom((short) 1); // single line border


        yellowFontStyle.setFont(fontYellow);

        setFontYellowStyle(yellowFontStyle);
    }

    private void createOrangeFontStyle() {
        XSSFFont fontOrange = workbook.createFont();
        fontOrange.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
        fontOrange.setColor(HSSFColor.ORANGE.index);
        fontOrange.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);

        XSSFCellStyle orangeFontStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        orangeFontStyle.setBorderTop((short) 1); // double lines border
        orangeFontStyle.setBorderLeft((short) 1);
        orangeFontStyle.setBorderRight((short) 1);
        orangeFontStyle.setBorderBottom((short) 1); // single line border
        orangeFontStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        orangeFontStyle.setFont(fontOrange);
        setFontOrangeStyle(orangeFontStyle);
    }

    private void createHeaderCellStyle() {
        XSSFCellStyle cellStyleHeaderRow = workbook.createCellStyle();

        cellStyleHeaderRow.setBorderTop((short) 1); // double lines border
        cellStyleHeaderRow.setBorderLeft((short) 1);
        cellStyleHeaderRow.setBorderRight((short) 1);
        cellStyleHeaderRow.setBorderBottom((short) 1); // single line border
        cellStyleHeaderRow.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cellStyleHeaderRow.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.BRIGHT_GREEN.index);
        cellStyleHeaderRow.setWrapText(true);

        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
        font.setBoldweight(XSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        cellStyleHeaderRow.setFont(font);

        setHeaderCellStyle(cellStyleHeaderRow);
    }

    private void createSheet(String sheetName) {
        setSheet(workbook.createSheet(sheetName));
    }

    private void getSheet(String sheetName) {
        setSheet(workbook.getSheet(sheetName));
    }

    private void createWorkBook() {
        setWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook());
    }

    private void createWorkBook(InputStream inp) {
        try {
            setWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(inp));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error while creating the workbook from the file, 
    details: " + e);
        }
    }

    private void createWorkBook(String filePath) {
        try {
            OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filePath);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(pkg);
            setWorkbook(wb);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while creating the workbook from the file, 
    details: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

ouput is like this, text color applied only to first row

[image: ouput is like this, text color applied only to first row]

Comment: When and how is `ExcelOutputWriter` instantiated? And when and how is `addBGVInformationVO` and `writeToOutputFile` called then? Please make the example reproducible, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Have you read the stackoverflow help page linked in my first comment? Please do not providing code in comments. You can editing your question and providing it there. Also provide a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example** if you wants help.

Answer (score 0):

For this question there are many things to say about apache poi and his objects .
I couldn't try your code because it's very custom code and objects you are using are missing .

Anyway let's say something about apache poi object library :

1. I want let to you read this article about [POI-HSSF and POI-XSSF](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/)

In my example below i used **XSSFWorkbook** and **XSSFSheet** instead of HSSFWorkbook and HSSFSheet, because with this it will limit you to 4000 max cells font and advise you with exception but in real when you reduce the number of cells font to set it will apply only for few cells,usually less than <40.

With **XSS** objects you will be able to apply your font to all the cells . 
When you work with large files you can get Java Heap Space exception so could be 
useful to increase it .

Below the code and a screenshot of the result :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class Main {

    public Main() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream is = null;
        XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
             is = new FileInputStream(new File("pathtofile\\myfile.xlsx"));
             wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
            String str = "1111";
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

            Cell cell =null;
            Font font =null;
            CellStyle style = null;
            for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){


            Row row =  sheet.createRow(i);
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            cell = row.createCell(j);
             font = wb.createFont();
             if(j % 2 ==0)
            font.setColor(HSSFColor.RED.index);
             else
                 font.setColor(HSSFColor.GREEN.index);
                 style = wb.createCellStyle(); 
                style.setFont(font);
                cell.setCellStyle(style); 
                cell.setCellValue(str);
            }

            }
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File("pathtofile\\myfile.xlsx"));
            wb.write(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(wb != null)
                wb.close();
            if(is !=null)
                is.close();
            if(out != null)
                out.close();
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

As you can notice i created a **.xlsx** file , which works with **XSS** objects and not **.XLS** file , read about [Difference Between XLS and XLSX](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-xls-and-xlsx/)

Comment: the issue is that styles are shown to the first row means code is working. but when i am appending data for 2nd row , the formatting is not working. why is it so?

Comment: Simply don't creating a font and a cell style for each cell if you really needs only two different cell styles having two different fonts. Create the two cell styles having two different fonts outside the `for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)...` loop and use one of the two `if(j % 2 ==0)` or `else`.